# how do I add "home" menu item conditionally to custom menus?

Tags: menus

**Original question**
*How do I get menu items using slug and not ID*

> I need to get a specific menu, but I can't use ID, since the menu ID
>   on my dev is not the same as on my staging and prod server.
>
> WP doc says that `wp_get_nav_menu_items`can be used with menu slug.
>   But how do I know what slug is created? I tested with what I thought
>   would be a slug, but I got no menu items.

My initial though was that I needed to fetch a menu in order to get menu items in an array / object so that I could add an extra menu item.

There is little documentation on how one can get a menu item by using a slug, so I got a bit stuck. If you should have the answer, please add this as well.

My goal was to add a 'home' link based on a specific condition.

Thanks to the feedback, I have rewritten my question so it makes more sense ;)

Comment: Four answers and no up vote. Guys, why did you think it was worth the time?

Comment: I've not upvoted yet, because (as I noted in a comment, below) I think the question is not written well enough (it doesn't actually ask what the OP is *trying to accomplish*). Once the OP rephrases the question, I will gladly up-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on your comment:

> `wp_nav_menu` is what I'm using now. But now I have to add 'home' menu item depending on certain criteria

I'm going to propose a solution that will allow you to add a "Home" menu item to *any* menu, based on arbitrary conditions, using the `wp_nav_menu_items` filter ([see tutorial here](http://wpfirstaid.com/tag/wp_nav_menu_items/)):

```
<?php
function wpse45802_add_nav_menu_home_link( $items, $args ) {
    $home_link = '';
    if ( INSERT CONDITIONALS HERE ) {
        // Determine menu item class
        $home_link_class = ( is_front_page() ? ' class="current-menu-item"' : '' );
        // Build home link markup
        $home_link = '<li' . $home_link_class . '>';
        $home_link .= $args->before;
        $home_link .= '<a href="' . home_url() . '">';
        $home_link .= $args->link_before . 'Home' . $args->link_after;
        $home_link .= '</a>';
        $home_link .= $args->after;
        $home_link .= '</li>';
    }
    // Merge home link menu item with nav menu items
    $modified_items = $home_link . $items;
    // Return the result
    return $modified_items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpse45802_add_nav_menu_home_link', 10, 2 );
?>
```

If you need to limit the filter further, perhaps to filter only certain `theme_location` outputs, let me know, and I'll update. Also, if you can describe your actual conditionals, I'll add those as well.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up using. You have to add one thing though. If condition is false, then you have to return `$items`, otherwise no menu items are returned.

Comment: Actually, the code above should *already* return `$items`. All it does is prepend `$items` with either home link markup or an empty string, before returning. Is it not doing so?

Comment: You are right. In my solution I didn't have the variable outside the `if` statement so I can concatenate the additional menu item. That's why it first return zero menu items.

Comment: Cool; I wanted to make sure. I always try to make it a habit *never* to modify the passed parameter directly, but only make changes in a separate variable, and then return the modified result. But, I wanted to make sure I didn't have a syntax error or something. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get menus using `theme_location` parameter, see [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters) page for more information.

This is how Twenty Eleven gets menu using this method - http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php#L118

Comment: `wp_nav_menu` is what I'm using now. But now I have to add 'home' menu item depending on certain criteria.

Comment: Would it not perhaps be more beneficial to re-phrase your question to ask *what you're ultimately trying to accomplish* - that is, **how to add "home" menu item conditionally to custom menus**?

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a specific menu? why not use a simpler function, `wp_nav_menu`, and pass an argument of your desirable menu name? just replace your menu name with $menu_name in the next example:

```
<?php 
$menu_args = array('menu' => $menu_name );
wp_nav_menu( $menu_args ); 
?>
```

more about that function: `http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu`

Comment: `wp_nav_menu` is what I'm using now. But now I have to add 'home' menu item depending on certain criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`wp_get_nav_menu_object`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L10) to get the nave menu by ID, slug or name (matches in that order).

```
 $menu_obj =wp_get_nav_menu_object($id_slug_or_name);
```

To get the menu object by theme location you can use this function ([see related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45700/display-menu-name-using-wp-nav-menu/45708#45708))

```
 function wpse45700_get_menu_by_location( $location ) {
  if( empty($location) ) return false;

  $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
  if( ! isset( $locations[$location] ) ) return false;

  $menu_obj = get_term( $locations[$location], 'nav_menu' );

  return $menu_obj;
}
```

Stored in the menu object `$menu_obj;` is the ID:`$menu_obj->ID;`

Of course, if you are simply displaying the menu, as the other two answers have said you can use [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) which accepts ID, slug or name (matches in that order)

Comment: Will I be able to add menu item to `menu_obj`?